# How to create twitter app with access token.?

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth, access-token

i want to create twitter app for auto posts from my website (update tweets from website to twitter),

when i try to create app, the **API key** and **API secret's** are created but for **Access Token** it asks to add phone number,

so i try to add phone number into my profile settings but getting the following **error**

**[image: error]**,

i cant complete my authentication section because of this error.

anyone know any solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are sorry about the inconvenience. If you are unfortunately unable to meet the mobile phone requirements from your country, please use this link to request more permissions for your application: https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform, and use the option "I have an API policy question not covered by these points". The Platform Operations team at Twitter will help you in the process.

We are aware of the current difficulties in some countries and actively working on improving the app registration and update flow. Thanks for your patience.